# C# .Net 2.0 послать get запрос

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый день, вот допустим у меня есть код который посылает гет запрос.

```
HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com?ll=12312");
WebResponse response = http.GetResponse();
```

Но после запуска программы, пишет вот это - **Возникло исключение "System.IO.IOException" в mscorlib.dll ("Заданного параметра реестра не существует.").** В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 2.0? Ретро, однако...

Comment: Советую вот тут почитать, здесь Microsoft дал исчерпывающий ответ: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773666/webrequest-create-eats-an-ioexception-on-the-first-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [этому топику](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618163/webrequest-create-throws-ioexception-the-specified-registry-key-does-not-exist/25765851#25765851), вам надо провести некоторые манипуляции с реестром:

Добавьте по пути `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` ключ с именем `LegacyWPADSupport` типа "dword" и значением `00000000`

И/или по пути `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework` ключ с тем же именем, типом и значением.

Comment: А на других ПК так же надо будет везде переключать? А то это не очень круто, когда надо значения в реестре менять перед запуском

Comment: @JoneGreen что ж вы со старичком работаете? :)